# RichtextBox Disable Auto Formatting Rtf

Tags: c#, formatting, rtf, richtext

When I change the Rtf property in the RichtextBox it is auto formatting it again. I want to avoid that because it deletes items from color, font and other tables.

```
"\b\b" -> "\b"
"\cf1 hello \cf3 world" -> color #2 in the color-table is getting deleted
//so that cf3 doesn't make any sense anymore
```

Can I disable this "auto formatting" ?

Comment: I would hesitate to do it that way — you end up fighting the RTF control.  What are you doing that necessitates manually changing the color table?

Comment: Use the RichTextBox's Text property to get the pure text. Putting this
text into the Rtf property should cancel any formatting still there.Also can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245758/removing-richtext-formatting-from-richtextbox-in-visual-c-sharp

Comment: @LarsTech I'm giving the color table colors that I probably will need. But if I don't use them the rtf control deletes them and makes my cf3 color to cf2 and then the whole thing is colored incorrectly because cf3 is still in the rtf code

Comment: @mini-me The RTF control was designed to be manipulated via SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties, followed by rtf attributes, such as SelectionColor = yada-yada-yada.  The answer to your question is no, you cannot disable the auto-generation of the rtf code from the control.

Comment: @LarsTech Not even with overriding stuff in RichTextBox ? And please make an answer. I can't accept comments ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RTF control was designed to be manipulated via `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` properties, followed by rtf attributes, such as `SelectionColor = yada-yada-yada`.  To manipulate the RTF data would require parsing the RTF string property, and that is fraught with difficulties to correctly identify rtf control characters and rtf text, along with keeping the font and color indexes in sync.

The answer to your question is no, you cannot disable the auto-generation of the rtf code from the control.